# PIL: selftest fails, but package shows status is fine?

Tags: python, centos, python-imaging-library, freetype

I have PIL installed with the required libraries (so I think). During installation it shows

```
*** TKINTER support not available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
--- LITTLECMS support available
```

However, when I run selftest.py, I get this:

```
*** PIL CORE support not installed
*** TKINTER support not installed
--- JPEG support ok
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support ok
*** FREETYPE2 support not installed
*** LITTLECMS support not installed
```

i.e. it's not detecting PIL CORE, FREETYPE2 and LITTLECMS.

I installed the following packages on CentOS 6.0 using python 2.6.5

```
libjpeg libjpeg-devel zlib zlib-devel freetype freetype-devel lcms lcms-devel
```

PIL was installed with ***pip install PIL***. However, the selftest was run from a source code from the offical PIL website.

Any ideas?

Comment: Uhh if im not mistaken CentOS ships with python 2.4, might wanna double check that selftest is ran from the correct interpreter

Comment: Try building the C extensions in-place in the source directory with `setup.py build_ext -i` before running `selftest.py` or `Tests\run.py`

Comment: @ArgsKwargs: CentOS 6.0 comes with Python 2.6.5: http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=centos 
Thanks for the heads up to though.

Comment: @cgohlke
That worked! Thanks! If you post that, I will mark it as solution. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try building the C extensions in-place in the source directory with `setup.py build_ext -i` before running `selftest.py` or `Tests\run.py`.